# Change the Cart´s Layout to Onepage

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, onepage-checkout

i would like to change the layout of the magento shopping cart to the same layout as the **Onepage-Checkout**.

Does anyone have *a quick idea how* to do this?

Comment: If you do not need the cart page at all you can write redirect from the cart page to the checkout page.

Answer (score 1):

Use `checkout.xml` file and set col1 for this .

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? Where is the `checkout.xml` file? Could you provide an XML example?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure about your onepage layout.As per as ,my concept most of Onepage checkout layout is 2columns-right.

so,you need to change page layout by:

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
 </checkout_cart_index>
```

Or open checkout.xml

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
        <label>Shopping Cart</label>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>
        <!-- Mage_Checkout -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
```

**to**

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
        <label>Shopping Cart</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
```